# Azure Functions - Speed up deployment, multiple zip files

Tags: deployment, azure-functions

I'm running an azure functions app with the zip package method. The app has a few dependencies (eg numpy and pandas) and is ~100mb. Each time I need to redeploy, vs code needs to repackage, upload the zip to azure storage, restart the app etc. Everything takes ~6mins.

Each redeploy may only be small changes to my code, but for the most part all the other packages remain static.

Is there a better way to structure this deployment? Zip seems to be the recommended/cleanest method, but most parts of this are redundant and take too long.

Eg is there a way to store multiple zip packages - one for big static packages, one for my own code?

What if the zip file grew much larger over time? What if I wanted to have multiple apps sharing the same packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Azure DevOps you can setup a continuous CI/CD pipeline using the build and release channel.

Here is a link that shows how to set that up: https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurefunctions/

This deployment will be triggered automatically everytime you push/merge into a branch (in my setup, whenever PR's into master is approved). The first thing it does is, it will build and create an artificact which the release pipeline will then use to deploy it automatically.

As far as I know, this is best way to do it. You can also use other build/release managers!